# Error con MySql JDBC conector 8 para java

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy trabajando con Jdk 11, Apache netbeans 11.2 y Driver MySQL conector 5.0.21 de java y funciona perfecto pero lo cambio por el Connector 8 que saque de esta página de mysql https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/ pero no me funciona Entra a SQLexeption. lo que deseo es trabajar con la última versión de conector de MYSQL para java. Muchas gracias

Comment: Cuál es exactamente el error?

Comment: En la consola solo me muestra SqlExeption 1 min así igual no muestra más no sé si es incompatible con Ese conector 8.0.19 ya que siempre use el 5.0.21

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Angelita verifica si el driver que tienes es el correcto ya que en la versión 5 se ocupa

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

pero en la 8 se cambia por

```
    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Nos ayudaria mucho si expones el código y el error que te muestra.